# How can I remove jenkins completely from linux

Tags: linux, jenkins

I have deleted jenkins all directories from different folders. But still when I access URL it is showing me jenkins login.

I want to uninstall jenkins completely. Have tried many commands from internet but still jenkins is there on server.

I have only command line access via putty so I tries whatever is possible via command to remove jenkins.

Comment: @HelpingHands - you can post in on http://askubuntu.com/ and http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

If your jenkins is running as service instead of process you should stop it first using

```
sudo service jenkins stop
```

After stopping it you can follow the normal flow of removing it using commands respective to your linux flavour

For centos it will be

```
sudo yum remove jenkins
```

For ubuntu it will

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge jenkins
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: I also had to run the `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list` and `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list.save` commands on my Ubuntu 16.04, because otherwise the system will look for jenkins updates on `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: On CentOS-like flavors of Linux, you would also need: `sudo rm -r /var/lib/jenkins` to get rid of all the preferences. If you reinstall after performing @mnpoonia's 3 steps, you will still have the same administrator password, for instance.

Comment: @DarkerIvy - This will remove the jenkins database of builds and workspaces but will not remove the jenkins user from the system.

Comment: On Centos (maybe on other Linux as well) the jenkins installation script automatically creates the jenkins user. sudo yum remove jenkins does not remove that user. If you want to Completely remove the jenkins installation you probably want to delete the user as well: sudo userdel jenkins

Answer (score 17):

if you are ubuntu user than try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove jenkins
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove jenkins
```

'apt-get remove' command is use to remove package.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: the command `sudo apt-get autoremove jenkins` worked for me! Is this functional exactly like `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove` jenkins which you suggested?

Answer (score 9):

On Centos7,
It is important to note that while you remove jenkins using following command:
sudo yum remove jenkins

it will not remove your users and other information. For that you will have to do following:
sudo rm -r /var/lib/jenkins

Answer (score 1):

First - stop Jenkins service:

```
sudo service jenkins stop
```

Next - delete:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge jenkins
```

If you used separate server for Jenkins, some GCP or AWS - just delete this server.
Here is a video how to uninstall Jenkins from GCP Compute Engine https://youtu.be/D2HUFAc_Trw

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You might consider using the space here to include any relevant information from the you tube video you link to. Stackoverflow best practice is to put as much info here.

Answer (score 1):

For sentOs, it's works for me
At first stop service by  `sudo service jenkins stop`

Than remove by `sudo yum remove jenkins`

Comment: This is wrong. this will still have users and other info, you will have to delete the file `/var/lib/jenkins` after the remove command, Checkout @Anand Desai 's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed Jenkins using snap and I completely forgot.
so if there is anyone out there who has tried all these steps and still gets Jenkins sign-in page try this thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49695931/9854536

Answer (score 0):

Anyone trying to uninstall jenkins should consider uninstalling it using
**`sudo snap remove jenkins`** in case you installed it using snap and forgot about it which was my case