# How to uninstall Jenkins when I installes jenkins by war file?

Tags: maven, jenkins, war

I installed Jenkins by using war file from official site, but I forget admin password so I reinstall Jenkins.

Then I tried to uninstall Jenkins, but I didn't find `/Library/Application Support/Jenkins/Uninstall.command` and I'm puzzled how to uninstall Jenkins.

Do you have some ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Kodama, that script is only needed if you have installed Jenkins using the installer on Mac OS X. If you have just deployed the war file on an application container/server or using the embedded application container, you just need to delete de war and your local configuration located at ~/.jenkins

Comment: Thank you, jperis. I've deleted war file ~/.jenkins but I can connect Jenkins via localhost:8080 ever.

Comment: Kodama, which OS are you using? Have you set jenkins as a service? If that the case, you have to uninstall the service.

Comment: @jperis, I use Mac OS version Capitan. I downloaded war file from [https://jenkins.io](https://jenkins.io) and `$ java -jar jenkins.war`. I haven't done anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu linux and jenkins. Turns out jenkins was installed as a  "snap", a new kind of Ubuntu installation. It was installed in /var/snap.  Here is info on [snaps](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy) which helped me. I used `sudo snap remove jenkins`