# How to remove Jenkins from ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I have jenkins which is consuming a lot of CPU. I want to delete it as I no longer need it.

[image]

I have tried `sudo service jenkins remove` but jenkins keeps working.
What can I do to permanently remove it from Ubuntu server?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove jenkins completely from linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604715/how-can-i-remove-jenkins-completely-from-linux)

Comment: I did all that is described there, but it doesn't work. When I do sudo apt-get autoremove jenkins it tells me jenkins is not installed, but I keep having jenkins in the running processes list.

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: yes, it s good now. thx

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands

```
sudo systemctl stop jenkins
sudo apt autoremove jenkins
sudo apt-get remove --purge jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

**use this using sudo**

```
systemctl stop jenkins
```

Check the status

```
systemctl status jenkins
```

To remove

```
apt autoremove jenkins
```